# What does "$str = preg_replace('/<[^>]+>/i',' ',$str)" mean?

Tags: php

```
function erase_tag($str){

    $str = preg_replace('/<[^>]+>/i'," ",$str);
    $str = preg_replace("/\s\s/"," ",$str);
    return $str;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

`preg_replace` uses regex:

```
/<[^>]+>/i
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

- `<` - *the literal character `<`*
- `[^>]+` - *any character that isn't (that's the `^`) a `>` matched 1 to infinity times (that's the `+`)*
- `>` - *the literal character `>`*

It replaces HTML tags (or anything else inside `<....>`) with a space. The `i` is an "in case sensitive" modifier and means nothing in this regex as we don't use any letters. An alternative is the in build [`strip_tags()`](http://www.php.net/strip_tags) function.

---

```
/\s\s/
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

- `\s` - *a single white space character*
- `\s` - *a single white space character*

It replaces 2 white-spaces after each other (tab, newline, space) with a single space. Personally I'd prefer `/\s+/` which matches 1 to an infinite amount of white spaces after each other.